React Native Text doesn't increase the height to fit to the contents
There is an issue where the height of the Text component does not properly draw the area of the contents when the font is bolded in the Android device's settings. adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}, numberOfLines={1} does not work, and numberOfLines is not a consideration, because the contents that can be in the second column can be values of different lengths, not just phone numbers, and we need to show all of them.
<View style={{ width: "100%", flexDirection: "row" }}>
  <Text style={{ width: 163 }}>Number</Text>
  <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>012-3456-7890</Text>
</View>

The last word 0 is hidden:

When it is given View.style a height: 80, the result is:

The 0 wasn't truncated or lost in the first screen shot, it just wasn't visible because the Text component didn't have enough space. In this case, if I removed the View.style.height and added another zero to the second column, it would look like this. This means that regardless of the View.style.height property, the height of the area should grow to match the length of the Text component's contents, and you can see that in the first case, the height of the Text component was not drawn high enough to match the length of the contents.

On your test device, set the font to bold in the device settings and adjust the width of the first column appropriately to reproduce the issue.
Is there any fundamental solution to resolve this issue?

According to the docs, setting numberOfLines={0} should allow the text to wrap. Also, adding flex to the containing View might help. Try this:
<View style={{ width: "100%", flexDirection: "row", flex: 1 }}>
  <Text style={{ width: 163 }} numberOfLines={0}>Number</Text>
  <Text style={{ flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap' }} numberOfLines={0}>012-3456-7890</Text>
</View>


It doesn't work for me.

maybe flexWrap: 'wrap'? I added it to the snippet

It's hard to test without a device (I didn't find that setting in the Android emulator), as the issue is caused by bolding fonts in the Android device settings, but running it on a real device still doesn't seem to fix the issue. Thanks!
